# TypeError deleting items in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, for-loop, floating-point

I have a nested dictionary like the following:

```
g = {
    'a': {
        1.55: {
            'CD': [1.55, 12],
            'LM': [1.55, 12],
        },
        1.45: {
            'AF': [1.45, 15],
        },
        1.6: {
            'NR': [1.6, 26],
        }
    }
}
```

I want to search through every element, and remove it if it has a 12 in the list. I've written the following code, but get a `TypeError`. I was wondering if anyone could help.

```
for  e, p in g.iteritems():
    for p,o in g[e].iteritems():
        if g[e][p][o][1]==12:
            del g[e][p][o]
```

Comment: Though it's unrelated to your current error, you will need to be really careful when using floating point values as dictionary keys. Due to floating point errors, you may not be able to exactly match the value again. For instance, `1.4 + 0.15` is not equal to `1.55`, which may cause unexpected issues. You may want to redesign your data structure to avoid the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `o` is a dictionary, you can't use it as an index, which is why you are receiving the `TypeError`.

The following code would do what you want, but I urge you to think of a better way you can organize your data.

```
for k1 in g.keys():
    for k2 in g[k1].keys():
        for k3 in g[k1][k2].keys():
            if 12 in g[k1][k2][k3]:
                del g[k1][k2][k3]
```

Note that you need to use `.keys()` instead of `.iterkeys()` to avoid `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`. Similarly, in @Eric's solution `.items()` should be used instead of `.iteritems()`

Comment: Would you say creating another separate dictionary with the attribute I want is faster than running these 3 for-loops? This dictionary could be quite large and these 3 for-loops would be run quite rarely.

Comment: Currently you are looking through each entry in your nested dictionary, which defeats the purpose of using a dictionary in the first place. If possible I would try and keep track of the reverse relationship in a list or set.

Answer (score 2):

Your immediate problem is that `o` is a dict, not a key, so indexing with `o` leads to a `KeyError`. You can see that by putting in a print statement:

```
for  e, p in g.iteritems():
    for p,o in g[e].iteritems():
        print(o)
```

yields

```
{'LM': [1.55, 12], 'CD': [1.55, 12]}
```

So `g[e][p][o]` raises a KeyError. You need to iterate through the items of `o` by adding another for-loop:

```
    for q, r in o.iteritems():
```

However, if you add that to your code, you'll then run into a `RunTimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`.
This is due to the fact that we are deleting a key-value pair from `o` while iterating over the items in `o`. Python does not like that.

You can avoid the issue of deleting items from `g` while iterating over `g` entirely by using a dict comprehension to *build* the desired dict:

```
g={'a':{1.55: {'CD': [1.55, 12], 'LM': [1.55, 12]}, 1.45: {'AF': [1.45, 15]}, 1.6: {'NR': [1.6, 26]}}}

g = {k1: {k2: {k3: v3 for k3, v3 in v2.iteritems() if v3[1] != 12}
      for k2, v2 in g[k1].iteritems()
      } for k1, v1 in g.iteritems()}

print(g)
# {'a': {1.55: {}, 1.45: {'AF': [1.45, 15]}, 1.6: {'NR': [1.6, 26]}}}
```